# How to dynamically create "Share This buttons" with a custom URLs with a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sharethis

im using the http://sharethis.com/ buttons to give users on a website a simple way to share content.

They have information on "custom buttons" here: http://help.sharethis.com/customization/custom-buttons

It looks like to specify the URL, in the example all they have its just html like this:

```
<span class="st_sharethis" st_url="http://mycustomurl.com" st_title="Sharing Rocks!"
displayText="ShareThis"></span>
```

But I need to be able to dynamically create buttons on the fly without reloading the page.

So, In a flash application i'm building i have a "share button" that triggers a javascript function on the webpage that makes a "popup" div fade into the center of the screen that I want to display the share buttons. Depending on what share button someone clicks it will need to have a dynamically created URL.

It's important if they close the dialog, then click the share button again, im hoping the code will just overwrite the old code with new buttons, with the new url/titles.

So, i created this javascript function that I call from flash, while passing the url from flash. I placed the script and everything inside my "popup" div, hoping that the buttons will be rendered inside that div.

```
function shareChannel(theurl)
{
//I cant seem to find an example of what to put here to load the buttons, and give them a custom URL and title

//finally display the popup after the buttons are made and setup.
displaypopup();
}
```

could anyone possibly post an example of how I might be able to do this without ever reloading the page?

EDIT:
@Cubed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function shareChannel(chaan)
          {

          document.getElementById('spID1').setAttribute('st_url', 'http://mycustomurl?chan='+chaan);
          document.getElementById('spID1').setAttribute('st_title', 'Custom Title is ['+chann+'] it works!');

          stButtons.locateElements();

          centerPopupThree();
          loadPopupThree();
          }

</script>
```

Basically nothing happens. I hate using javascript because I really have no idea how to get error messages or debug. When I work with flex, I have a great debugger/console to messaround with. So, sorry im having trouble providing more info. I did notice when I remove just the

```
document.getElementById('spID1').setAttribute('st_url', 'http://mycustomurl?chan='+chaan);
              document.getElementById('spID1').setAttribute('st_title', 'Custom Title is ['+chann+'] it works!');
```

The popup appears.

But if I have the above setAttribute code inside the function, the popup never appears, so im assuming something in that code is breaking it. Any suggestions? Or at least a way I could use chrome to tell me what the error is? I tried the inspect element console but there was nothing that appeared there when i triggered the function.

Also, in at the top of my code they had me use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'mypubidgoeshere'});</script>
```

Should I be using 
`stLight.locateElements();` rather than `stButtons.locateElements();`

Comment: There's a typo in the code, you have 'chann' and 'chaan', that's why it's not working, change 'chann' to 'chaan' for the title and it should work wonders. For the record the Tools>Javacript console in chrome will get you to the debugger. If you go there before you change, it should have an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: chann is not defined'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've been using the

```
stButtons.locateElements();
```

function to generate any new buttons after loading content via AJAX, I imagine it will work for this too.

This question might be of some assistance also:

[Sharethis button does not work on pages loaded via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768539/sharethis-button-does-not-work-on-pages-loaded-via-ajax)

Better Solution:

Make your `<div>` and make sure all the `<span>`s have IDs, otherwise you can give them classes but you will need to iterate through them all.

```
function shareChannel(theurl, thetitle)
    {
    document.getElementById('spanID1').setAttribute('st_url', theurl);
    document.getElementById('spanID1').setAttribute('st_title', thetitle);

    stButtons.locateElements();

    //finally display the popup after the buttons are made and setup.
    displaypopup();
    }
```

Comment: So, you're saying I would just make the span classes in the html...Then what I could do is in my function that's triggered from the flash...just use `stButtons.locateElements();` to somehow alter the URL/TITLE when the function is ran? Would you mind showing me how it's used to alter the url/title? Sorry, im pretty good with actionsctipt. Very new to javascript and ajax. Sorry!

Comment: is that what your after? It's a bit rough.

Comment: awesome, that makes sense. That looks like exactly what im trying to do...but after a test It's simply not working. I posted some information above. Mind taking a quick look at the edit? Thanks a lot!