# Ajax how to load some scripts

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, smarty, sharethis

I have the following code, that loads to an unerdored list content, depending on how much span there is with information:

```
$(document).on('click','#addplaylisttolist',function(){
    myPlaylist.pause();
    myPlaylist.remove();
    $("#playlist_selected_songs").empty();
    $.each($(this).find("span"),function(){
            $("#playlist_individual_li").load('listen_playlist_section_content_item_add',{musicId:$(this).attr('data-id-music'),musicTitle:$(this).attr('data-title'),musicArtist:$(this).attr('data-artist'),musicFile:$(this).attr('data-mp3'),musicPoster:$(this).attr('data-poster'),musicTime:$(this).attr('data-time-music')},function(){
                $("#playlist_selected_songs").append($("#playlist_individual_li").html());
            });
        });
    myPlaylist.play();
});
```

The code where the playlist will be build:

```
    <div class="m-t-n-xxs item pos-rlt">
        <div class="top text-right">
            <span class="musicbar animate bg-success bg-empty inline m-r-lg m-t" style="width:25px;height:30px">
                <span class="bar1 a3 lter"></span>
                <span class="bar2 a5 lt"></span>
                <span class="bar3 a1 bg"></span>
                <span class="bar4 a4 dk"></span>
                <span class="bar5 a2 dker"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="playlist_owner_info" class="bottom gd bg-info wrapper-lg">
            <span id="playlist_owner_info_followers" class="pull-right text-sm">
                            {$item.profile_jrFollower_item_count}
                            <br>
                            Followers
            </span>
            <span id="playlist_owner_info_name" class="h2 font-thin">
                            {$item.profile_name}
            </span>
        </div>
        {jrCore_module_function function="jrImage_display" module="jrProfile" type="profile_image" id="playlist_owner_img" class="img-full halfwidth" item_id=$item.profile_id size="medium" alt="..." crop="height"}
    </div>
    <ul id="playlist_selected_songs" class="list-group list-group-lg no-radius no-border no-bg m-t-n-xxs m-b-none auto">
        {$playlist = json_decode($item.playlist_list,true)}
        {foreach $playlist as $id => $position}
            {foreach $position as $id1 => $position1}
                {jrCore_list module="jrAudio" search="_item_id in `$id1`" template="listen_playlist_section_content_item.tpl"}
            {/foreach}
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
    <li id="playlist_individual_li" style="display: none;"></li>
```

The code of the midle div, where there is the list of playlists and where there is the anchor with the id "addplaylisttolist" that the top script uses:

```
{jrCore_module_url module="jrPlaylist" assign="purl"}
{if isset($_items)}
    {foreach from=$_items key="module" item="item"}
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
            <a id="addplaylisttolist" class="jp-play-me pull-right m-t-sm m-l text-md">
                {$playlist = json_decode($item.playlist_list,true)}
                {foreach $playlist as $id => $position}
                    {foreach $position as $id1 => $position1}
                            {jrCore_list module="jrAudio" search="_item_id in `$id1`" template="listen_playlist_item.tpl"}
                    {/foreach}
                {/foreach}
                <i class="icon-control-play text" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
            </a>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(document).on('click','#addplaylisttolist',function(){
                                $("#playlist_owner_img").attr('src','http://site.fm/profile/image/profile_image/{$item.profile_id}/medium/crop=height/_v=1456534488');
                                $("#playlist_owner_info_followers").html("{$item.profile_jrFollower_item_count}<br>Followers");
                                $("#playlist_owner_info_name").html("{$item.profile_name}");
                            });
                        });
                </script>

         ...
        </li>
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

And that anchor with the id "addplaylisttolist" will have has much span's with info as much musics the playlist in question has:

```
{jrCore_module_url module="jrAudio" assign="murl"}
{if isset($_items)}
    {foreach $_items as $item}
        <span id="artistitem" data-id-music="{$item._item_id}" data-time-music="{$item.audio_file_length}" data-title="{$item.audio_title}" data-artist="{$item.audio_file_artist}" data-mp3="{$jamroom_url}/{$murl}/stream/audio_file/{$item._item_id}/key=[jrCore_media_play_key]/file.mp3" data-poster="{$jamroom_url}/{$murl}/image/audio_image/{$item._item_id}/large" data-path="{$jamroom_url}/{$item.profile_url}/{$murl}/{$item._item_id}/{$item.audio_title_url}">
        </span>
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Finnaly, the problem is that the template i use to construct each individual li (used by the script at the top), is the following:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="pull-right m-l">
        <span class="addtolistbutton">
            {jrCore_module_function function='jrPlaylist_button' playlist_for='jrAudio' item_id=$musicId class='circleplus_icon_playlist' title='Add To Playlist'}
        </span>
        {if jrUser_is_logged_in()}
            <a href="" id="listen_playlist_delete_item" title="delete music"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>
        {/if}
        {literal}
            <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {var switchTo5x=true;});</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {stLight.options({ publisher: "123456789-91211-121314-121617-181920212223242526", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});});</script>

            <span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>

        {/literal}
    </div>
    <a href="" class="addplaylistmusic jp-play-me m-r-sm pull-left" data-title="{$musicTitle}" data-artist="{$musicArtist}" data-mp3="{$musicFile}" data-m4a="{$musicFile}" data-poster="{$musicPoster}">
        <i class="icon-control-play text"></i>
        <i class="icon-control-pause text-active"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="clear text-ellipsis">
        <a href="$(this).attr('data-path')"><span>
                {$musicTitle}
                </span></a>
        <span class="text-muted"> --
            {$musicTime}
                </span>
    </div></li>
```

As can be seen, there is scripts there. Using ajax with that scripts don't work. Does anyone knows a way i can make it work? Thanks.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

A concrete example:

```
<a id="addplaylisttolist" class="jp-play-me pull-right m-t-sm m-l text-md">


                            <!-- BEGIN wmMusic/listen_playlist_item.tpl -->

            <span id="artistitem" data-id-music="50" data-time-music="00:02:48" data-title="09   Skin To Bone" data-artist="L㏌k㏌ ㎩rk" data-mp3="http://site.fm/audio/stream/audio_file/50/key=1/file.mp3" data-poster="http://site.fm/audio/image/audio_image/50/large" data-path="http://site.fm/userdemo1/audio/50/09-skin-to-bone">
        </span>

<!-- END wmMusic/listen_playlist_item.tpl -->


                            <!-- BEGIN wmMusic/listen_playlist_item.tpl -->

            <span id="artistitem" data-id-music="49" data-time-music="00:01:51" data-title="07   Victimized" data-artist="L㏌k㏌ ㎩rk" data-mp3="http://site.fm/audio/stream/audio_file/49/key=1/file.mp3" data-poster="http://site.fm/audio/image/audio_image/49/large" data-path="http://site.fm/userdemo1/audio/49/07-victimized">
        </span>

<!-- END wmMusic/listen_playlist_item.tpl -->


                                                    <i class="icon-control-play text" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
            </a>
```

And at the left side appears:

```
<ul id="playlist_selected_songs" class="list-group list-group-lg no-radius no-border no-bg m-t-n-xxs m-b-none auto"><!-- BEGIN wmMusic/listen_playlist_section_content_item_add.tpl -->
<li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="pull-right m-l">
        <span class="addtolistbutton">
            <!-- BEGIN jrPlaylist/playlist_button.tpl -->
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="playlist_button_jrAudio_50">    
    <a onclick="jrPlaylist_select('50','jrAudio',null)" title="add to playlist"><link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="http://site.fm/core/icon_css/32?_v=1462732449"><span class="sprite_icon sprite_icon_32"><span class="sprite_icon_32 sprite_icon_32_img sprite_icon_32_music">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
    <div id="playlist_jrAudio_50" class="overlay playlist_box" style="position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;"><!-- playlist loads here --></div>
</div>
<!-- END jrPlaylist/playlist_button.tpl -->
        </span>
                    <a href="" id="listen_playlist_delete_item" title="delete music"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>

        <div id="test"></div>

    </div>
    <a href="" class="addplaylistmusic jp-play-me m-r-sm pull-left" data-title="09   Skin To Bone" data-artist="L㏌k㏌ ㎩rk" data-mp3="http://site.fm/audio/stream/audio_file/50/key=1/file.mp3" data-m4a="http://site.fm/audio/stream/audio_file/50/key=1/file.mp3" data-poster="http://site.fm/audio/image/audio_image/50/large">
        <i class="icon-control-play text"></i>
        <i class="icon-control-pause text-active"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="clear text-ellipsis">
        <a href="$(this).attr('data-path')"><span>   
                09   Skin To Bone
                </span></a>
        <span class="text-muted"> --
            00:02:48
                </span>
    </div></li>

<!-- END wmMusic/listen_playlist_section_content_item_add.tpl --><!-- BEGIN wmMusic/listen_playlist_section_content_item_add.tpl -->
<li class="list-group-item active">
    <div class="pull-right m-l">

        <span class="addtolistbutton">
            <!-- BEGIN jrPlaylist/playlist_button.tpl -->

<div style="display: inline-block;" id="playlist_button_jrAudio_49">

    <a onclick="jrPlaylist_select('49','jrAudio',null)" title="add to playlist"><link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="http://site.fm/core/icon_css/32?_v=1462732449"><span class="sprite_icon sprite_icon_32"><span class="sprite_icon_32 sprite_icon_32_img sprite_icon_32_music">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
    <div id="playlist_jrAudio_49" class="overlay playlist_box" style="position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;"><!-- playlist loads here --></div>
</div>
<!-- END jrPlaylist/playlist_button.tpl -->
        </span>
                    <a href="" id="listen_playlist_delete_item" title="delete music"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>            
        <div id="test"></div>

    </div>
    <a href="" class="addplaylistmusic jp-play-me m-r-sm pull-left active" data-title="07   Victimized" data-artist="L㏌k㏌ ㎩rk" data-mp3="http://site.fm/audio/stream/audio_file/49/key=1/file.mp3" data-m4a="http://site.fm/audio/stream/audio_file/49/key=1/file.mp3" data-poster="http://site.fm/audio/image/audio_image/49/large">
        <i class="icon-control-play text"></i>
        <i class="icon-control-pause text-active"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="clear text-ellipsis">
        <a href="$(this).attr('data-path')"><span>

                07   Victimized
                </span></a>
        <span class="text-muted"> --
            00:01:51
                </span>
    </div></li>

<!-- END wmMusic/listen_playlist_section_content_item_add.tpl --></ul>
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? From your question I could get what is the problem and how js and html is related, since you are referring to `id`s that are not in your html.

Comment: @Uzbekjon i added more code to make it easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: @Nmaster88 We need the html output, not the view template.

Comment: @Hors Sujet if it's an example you're talking about, i added one.

Comment: @Nmaster88 See my answer, *but we need more informations to help you.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding the content (in your [ajax success callback function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition)), call :

```
stButtons.locateElements();
```

See :

- [How to dynamically create "Share This buttons" with a custom URLs with a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289021/how-to-dynamically-create-share-this-buttons-with-a-custom-urls-with-a-javascr)
- [Sharethis button does not work on pages loaded via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768539/sharethis-button-does-not-work-on-pages-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: But still i'm missing some code to use that. What code do i need to use? Thanks

Comment: When you load site.com/listen with your ajax function. Add this line in the end of your success callback.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to be able to call the script functions that are within the dynamically added script tags. Correct?

Here are some things you can try:

- A) Try using global script functions and invoking them in the script tags (I am not sure what $function() does).
- B) Within the functions, try to invoke a debug alert('debug'). This may help you to see if the function is being invoked or not.
- C) When are the script functions invoked? It could be possible that the app is trying to invoke the functions Before the scripts have been fully loaded (using option A will help solve this). Another way is to somehow ensure that the scripts are loaded before invoking what's in them.
- D) For the script containing http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js, can't you just load this at the top of the page rather than dynamically like this?